# Missing Deployment Project Type in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, packaging, setup-deployment, visual-studio-express

I am not a full time programmer, but have to do a little bit to build tools to support my job. I have finished writing my application which I now need to deploy.

I do not want to use "ClickOnce" as I need to alter files in the 'local' folder at configuration time. My understanding is that if I use the Publish option under the Build menu, then I am using "ClickOnce".

My research has led me to believe that "You do this by adding one or more deployment projects to your solution". MSDN then states, that to acheive this  I need to select 'Add Project' and "In the resulting Add New Project dialog box, select the Setup and Deployment Projects folder."

The problem is, I do not have such an option ?!

Can someone shed some light on why this would be the case, and how I go about fixing it. I have spent half a day googling and cannot come up with a way forward?

Details of Project and System are as follows:

Environment: Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop.
Current Project: Windows Form Application.
Op Sys: Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 1):

Correct though its advice may be, that is an old tutorial that you're reading. It is probably referring to Visual Studio 2010.

[That option has been removed in VS 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx). You will need to use an alternative tool to build your installer. For example:

- [WiX](http://wix.codeplex.com/)
- [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)
- [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/)
- …etc.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest looking at Wix#.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31407/Wix-WixSharp-managed-interface-for-WiX.  If you are doing your coding in C#, Wix# this would probably be the most simple and comfortable skill set to add, and it is free and would directly integrate into the Visual Studio environment you are using.

More info at the CodePlex home page for Wix#: http://wixsharp.codeplex.com/

For C# developers needing to create a Windows Installer MSI to deploy their app, Wix# is perhaps the best replacement for the "Packaging and Deployment" project type that Microsoft removed from Visual Studio starting with VS2012. Wix is a C# front end for the WiX (Windows Installer Xml) Toolset.  Using Wix# allows building a complete Windows Installer MSI in the C# language.

Wix# is useful for a broad range of installation/deployment scenarios, and lends itself reasonably well to Continuous Integration scenarios.  There are Wix# examples for deploying Windows desktop applications, for installing Windows Services, and installing ASP.NET websites, and many more types of installations.

The question mentioned a need to install applications on Windows 7.  Wix# supports this environment, and handles typical installer requirements, and the Wix# installer code for simple projects is indeed simple.  For application installs that are more complex, and require advanced features, Wix# can tap into the power of the full WiX Toolset when needed.  For example, when installing a .NET application, a typical requirement would be to install the application exe and dll files, and tailor some .NET configuration files and/or registry entries on the target system.

Below is an example of the C# code for a simple Wix# installer that installs an application on a target system, and modifies some configuration files.  This example assumes that you have written a utility named "TailorMyConfig.exe", e.g., a simple C# program that uses ConfigurationManager.AppSettings routines, and you are deploying this exe along with your app.

```c#
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using WixSharp;

class Script
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var project = new Project("MyProduct",
                          new Dir(@"%ProgramFiles%\My Company\My Product",
                              new File(@"Files\Bin\MyApp.exe"),
                              new File(@"Files\Bin\TailorMyConfig.exe")),
                          new ManagedAction("UpdateConfigFile"));

        project.Id = new Guid("6f330b47-2577-43ad-9095-1861ba25889b");

        Compiler.BuildMsi(project);
    }
}

public class MyCustomAction
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult UpdateConfigFile(Session session)
    {
        if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Config file update ready to run.\n Update config file(s) now?", 
                                                "Config Tailoring Utility",
                                                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
        {
            Process.Start("TailorMyConfig.exe", "Run utility to tailor config file to current system");
        }
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Note that there are "better" ways to modify a config file using WiX XML features. For simplicity, the example above assumed a custom-written C# exe utility for modifying config files.  I would suggest using WiX XML capabilities for doing this instead.  You can incorporate nearly any WiX XML capabilities directly into your Wix# setup using the Wix# technique of "XML injection".

Remember, Wix# is simply a C# front end that emits WiX XML syntax.  After Wix# has emitted the WiX XML (wxs file), that wxs file can easily be post-processed to insert additional WiX XML features.  Then the resulting wxs file gets compiled by the WiX Toolset into an MSI.

For an example of using XML Injection to incorporate WiX XML features into a Wix# (C#)installation, look here [In Wix#, how to avoid creating a physical folder on the target system, when deploying only registry entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558933/in-wix-how-to-avoid-creating-a-physical-folder-on-the-target-system-when-depl/26600575#26600575) 
In that question, see my answer that uses the technique of hooking up a delegate to the "WixSourceGenerated" event.

You could then use this XML injection approach to insert some WiX XML into your installer that would accomplish the config file editing.  An example of some typical WiX XML to modify config files is here: 
[How to modify .NET config files during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289773/how-to-modify-net-config-files-during-installation)

Another typical requirement of an installer would be to add or modify Windows Registry entries on a target system. Wix# provides direct support for that using the "RegValue" class.  The advantage there is when using Wix# you also get a full "uninstall" capability for free, including  uninstalling/reverting registry entries to the pre-install state.  This is a natural result of Wix# being built on top of the WiX Toolset and Windows Installer technology.  An example of a registry-only Wix# installer is here: [In Wix#, how to avoid creating a physical folder on the target system, when deploying only registry entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558933/in-wix-how-to-avoid-creating-a-physical-folder-on-the-target-system-when-depl/26600575#26600575)

The Wix# approach has been very useful in my environment, and it allows use of the familiar C# skillset without having to jump headfirst into the full complexity of the WiX XML installer technology.