# Editing file with msi-installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need update some software without replacing software's config-file. But this config-file must be upgraded (add some lines). Is it possible to edit the config-file with msi (created by wix) without replacing it?

```
<Component Id="com6e3e974d3fe541ed8554485c716e6f40" Guid="{841fb431-8a04-4ee8-a53f-80a5af8f3aa3}">
      <RemoveFile Id="A21" Name="N4GWSRV.exe.config" On="install" /> 
      <File Id="fil20a15c96a7db4fa7924651e80c05764e" Name="N4GWSRV.exe.config" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" Source="C:\ATM\N4GWSrv\N4GWSRV.exe.config" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289773/how-to-modify-net-config-files-during-installation If you need something more complex you'll probably have to create a custom action.

Comment: Great! It works, thank You very much! But one moment: creatd lines looks like <TestLine>TestValue</TestLine>, but I need they look like <add key="Debug" value="0"/>

Comment: I found answer for my second question here http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2009/05/27/from-msi-to-wix-part-25-installable-items-updating-xml-files-using-xmlfile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adrian Faciu for link [How to modify .NET config files during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289773/how-to-modify-net-config-files-during-installation)

also helped http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2009/05/27/from-msi-to-wix-part-25-installable-items-updating-xml-files-using-xmlfile.aspx