# How do I find executables when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio solution with a number of C# application projects.

```
Solution/
    A/
    B/
    C/
    Installer (WiX)/
```

Some of these executables need to be able to run others.  For example, A needs to be able to run B and C.  This is easy once the entire package is installed, since the executables will all get installed to the same location.  However, I am unsure how to find `B.exe` from `A.exe` when I am running the programs from inside Visual Studio, i.e., when I am testing and debugging.

How do I get the correct path, no matter if I running from Visual Studio or after installing the program fully?  I have some ideas, but I am a bit frustrated with execution, and I'm hoping it's easier than it currently seems.  I am comfortable editing the `*.csproj` files manually if that's what it takes.

### Possible solution 1

I could put the paths in the `App.config` files.  However, there are problems:

- The files would need to be different for debug and release versions.  This doesn't look easy.  [An answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud/7195232) recommends XSLT, which is somewhat pathological in its complexity and I especially don't want to learn *yet another language* just to solve such a simple problem.
- I would need to edit the file before it gets included in the installer, which is possible ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289773/how-to-modify-net-config-files-during-installation)) but requires yet more code.

### Possible solution 2

I could put the necessary paths in plain text files that are created using post-build steps, but I don't know enough batch scripting to be comfortable with this.

### Possible solution 3

Somehow copy `B.exe` into the output directory for A, so `B.exe` is always in the same path relative to `A.exe`.  This would be annoying, since there are already post-build steps which copy a bunch of dependencies for `B.exe`, and the files would need to be copied again during A's build process.

### Possible solution 4

Somehow adjust the build process so there is only one output directory shared between all projects in the solution.

### Non-solutions

I'd like to keep the solution so that it works after checking out a fresh copy of the repository from version control, which means that environment variables or command-line parameters won't work.

Comment: I would go with option 4. It's easy to configure each project to build to the same folder.

Comment: option 4 is the most logical one

Comment: Solution 5: Add them as references so VS will copy them to the project being run.

Comment: @leppie: From what I understand, if I add B as a reference in A, B will also get linked in to A.  How do I avoid this?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: What do mean 'linked in'? You are not actually referring to it in code, so no reference will exist in the assembly. The only side-effect is the project (exe and config and references) is copied and that seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @leppie: What I mean by "linked in" is that the linking phase will produce an assembly "A" with a reference to assembly "B", which is not what I want.  This is the process by which e.g. you can use functions in a library, if "B" is a library, but it also works for executables.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: IF no reference in code is made, there will be no reference in the resulting assembly either. Try it, should be exactly what you want. I do use this approach in some of my projects.