# How to modify C# standard config files during InstallShield installation?

Tags: installshield

how to modify C# standard app config files during InstallShield installation? Based on user answers. thank you.

Update: according to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289773/how-to-modify-net-config-files-during-installation) the only correct way is WIX. But InsatllShield is the corporate standard in our company. And that answer is dated 2014. Maybe nowadays InstallShield have some progress?

Comment: Do you want to change config files while installation of an installer that you made from InstallShield ?
If yes, then there is an option of INI file chnages in InstallShield. You can try that. Using that you can change any config files while installation in Post-Install section.

Comment: The target are .Net app config files - in XML format. The guy responsible in my team for creating InstallShield installations said that it's possible: one should ask user to enter value V during installation process specify name of XML file, XPath and overwrite old value with value V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield has had XML changes (XPath based) support for atleast the past 12 years or so.  In fact, I'd say it has better support then WiX because it also has a built in capability to search/read data from XML files also.

Why is this important?  Because MSI doesn't support persisting properties across transactions and you need the ability to read the value otherwise your custom value will get reset during repairs and upgrades.